# Adobe Air app signed with Cocomo certificate works on WIndows but not Mac

Tags: actionscript-3, air, certificate

I have signed an Adobe AIR desktop app using a `Cocomo Certificate`.  When I install on a Mac, the publisher is `UNKNOWN`.  But the same .air file sent to a windows user is OK and installs as any signed app should.

Why should this happen?  A certificate working on one OS, but not the other?

How can I investigate further? - to determine the cause.

Here are some more details:

The Certificate was obtained by a colleague on their PC.  They converted it to a `.pfx` file, and sent me the `.pfx`, along with the password they used.  I built the signed air app on my Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is: in addition to the main .p12/.pfx key for the AIR build process, you should try to use Mac Ceritificate (Developer ID Application: http://c2n.me/3qcrChL.png ). It helped me. The certificate might be got on the Apple Developers website: https://developer.apple.com (if you have a subscription).

In my case I was able to install .dmg on my MacBook Pro (where the .dmg file was created), but other users weren't able to install (when I send the file through the Internet or Skype).

Actually, the very process of signing is not clear. In my case I had to go through few steps:

1) Create .dmg (regular Adobe AIR build)

2) Deploy it

3) Sign the folder inside of it, something like dmg-folder-name/Contents/Resources/application-filename/Contents/MacOS/application-filename (where "dmg-folder-name" is sort of combination of the filename of the application + ".app", "application-name" is the filename of your application)

4) Sign the folder dmg-folder-name/Contents/MacOS/dmg-volume-name (where "dmg-volume-name" is something like "Install " + the filename of the application)

5) Sign the main dmg-folder

6) Create the new .dmg based on the signed files

It took a lot of time for me to figure out the correct solution. Also, please, pay attention to the order of steps, because it's IMPORTANT to sign the content of the main folder before you sign the main dmg-folder!

Also, I was able to find the topic on the Adobe website: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1470113 . It has a lot of suggestions and some of them don't workd in my case, but some of them helped me to find a solution.

Comment: I managed to create a mac installer that works.  But there's a problem.  My server requests don't work.  These are based on the mx.rpc.http.HTTPService class.